# fastest way to parse large text in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a 20MB 1 million line file in the following format:

```
# REG A
TextToParse1
TextToParse2
...
...
...
TestToParseX
# reg A
# REG B
TextToParse1
TextToParse2
...
...
...
TestToParseX
# reg B
(continued)
```

about 20k blocks in the mentioned format. 
I perform lookups in the file using a list `REG Z, REG YYY, REG C, REG ASDSX (order is random)`. On each iteration I capture the relevant text between `# REG X` and `# reg X`, process it, and continue to the next one in list. I'm looking for the fastest method to achieve it.

I went the regex approach. I timed a single lookup and my measurements show that:

```
start = timer()
pattern = r"(# REG {0})(.*)(# reg {0})".format(reg_name)
match = re.search(pattern, file, re.DOTALL)
end = timer()
```

is 0.2 seconds. This times 20k is very slow.

Comment: Try with `(# REG {0}\b)(.*)(# reg {0}\b)`

Comment: about 0.01 difference

Comment: One solution would be to match only the position of `# reg X` marker with [something like this](https://repl.it/EHiy/0) and then substring/parse your file with this indexes

Comment: Does the order in which you process the text impact the final output? I.e., is your final output just the sum of independent regex outputs?

Comment: 20k regex lookups are independent of each other, so it is just the sum of them.

Comment: Try an unrolled regex like [`# REG {0}([^#]*(?:#(?! reg {0})[^#]*)*)# reg {0}`](https://regex101.com/r/bdQDrW/1) (no dotall required).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you forgot a parenthesis ?

Comment: Are the REG lines the only lines that starts with `#` (excluding an eventual header at the start of the file)?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte no, there are other python comments

Comment: Well, there is another way to unroll the pattern - [`^# REG A(.*(?:\r?\n(?!# reg {0}).*)*)\r?\n# reg A`](https://regex101.com/r/bdQDrW/2) (with `re.M` option).

Comment: The fastest way is probably to not use regex (or at least not a full regex way).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 0.006s for your first version, wow! How does it work? I mean, how come its 2 orders of mag faster?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, have anything else in mind? I don't think string methods will be faster

Comment: I will post with a bit of an explanation then.

Comment: @susdu: yes, are you sure the file is well formatted? (for each REG X there's a reg X)

Comment: yes, well formatted

Comment: 20 MB is not _that_ much. Just read the entire file into memory and use a dictionary to map region labels to their content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern with `.*` implies some backtracking, and the amount of backtracking depends on how long the text is, whether or not you used the DOTALL modifier or not, whether there is a match or not. You enabled DOTALL mode, so, once the `# REG A` is found, the regex engine grabs the whole text with `.*` and starts backtracking in search for the end delimiter, `# reg A`. It might be a long way before the text is found.

What can be done? If your file is properly formatted, and your blocks are short (from the start till end delimiters), it should be enough to use lazy dot matching:

```
pattern = r"# REG {0}(.*?)# reg {0}".format(reg_name)
```

This should be still used with `re.DOTALL`.

If the blocks are very long, lazy dot matching loses in performance to unrolled patterns:

```
pattern = r'# REG {0}([^#]*(?:#(?! reg {0})[^#]*)*)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bdQDrW/3)

- `# REG {0}` -  the start delimiter pattern
- `([^#]*(?:#(?! reg {0})[^#]*)*)` - Group 1

  - `[^#]*`  - zero or more non-`#`
  - `(?:#(?! reg {0})[^#]*)*` - zero or more sequences of

    - `#(?! reg {0})` - a `#` char not followed with space+`reg`+space+name
    - `[^#]*` - zero or more non-`#`

This way, we get to the trailing delimiter by consuming the chunks not  matching the trailing delimiter in a linear way.

If the delimiters are always at the start of the lines, you could use `(?m)^# REG {0}(.*(?:\r?\n(?!# reg {0}).*)*)` regex using the same technique.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
with open('file.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith('# REG '):
            reg = line.split()[2]
            blocklist = []
            for line in fh:
                if line.startswith('# reg '):
                    # do what you need here
                    # print(reg)
                    # print(block)
                    block = ''.join(blocklist)
                    break
                blocklist.append(line)
```

*(Feel free to make a generator with it)*

using itertools:

```
from itertools import takewhile

with open('file.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith('# REG '):
            reg = line.split()[2]
            block = ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: not(x.startswith('# reg ')), fh))
            # do what you want here
            # print(reg)
            # print(block)
```

using regex:

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as fh:
    blocks = re.findall(r'(?m)^# REG (.*)\n((?:.*\n)*?)# reg ', fh.read())
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach, but you have `for line in fh` twice (surely a mistake). Also, it would be better to make `block` a list and `append` rather than use an immutable string

Comment: `for line in fh` twice isn't a mistake at all *(it avoids to test the other if condition until the end of the block)*, but you are right about list+append. I'm actually considering to use itertools.takewhile

Comment: why twice? why not simply de-indent the second `if` statement (and remove `break`)?

Comment: to avoid to test `if line.startswith('# REG '):` for nothing.

Comment: nice solution, measured 0.1s. The unrolled regex approach is faster though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for lines that start with either `# REG` or `# reg`, there's no need to use regular expressions at all. This should suffice:

```
def loadmyfile(filename):
    reg = ""
    nlp = 0
    for line in open(filename,"r"):
        if line[:6] == "# REG ":
            reg = line[6:]
        elif line[:6] == "# reg ":
            reg = ""
        else:
            # (Process the data here)
            nlp += 1
    print "Number of lines processed: %d" % nlp
```